# Evaluating the determinants of matrices A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am stuck on a homework question that asks to evaluate the det(A) and det(B). We are only given the following information: A and B are 3x3 matrices, such that **det((2A)⁻¹Bᵀ)=1** and **det(4B⁻¹A³)=1/2**, how could I solve this?

Comment: Do you know the fact that $det(AB)=det(A)det(B),det(kA)=k^ndet(A)$ and $det(A^{-1})=det(A)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

$\det (AB) = \det (A)\det(B)\\
\det (A^n) = \det (A)^n\\
\det (A^{-1}) = \frac 1{\det(A)}$

Transposition does not change determinants

Scalar multiplication multiplies every element in $A$ by that scalar.

When we take the determinant that scalar gets multiplied repeatedly equal to the number of rows in the matrix.

$\det (cA) = c^n\det(A)$

let $a = \det A, b = \det B$

$\det ((2A)^{-1}B^T) = \frac b{8a} = 1$

You can work out the other one, and then solve for $a, b$

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to work this out for $n \times n$ matrices, since there is really no more effort involved.

The solution depends almost entirely on the three properties

$\det(XY) = (\det X)(\det Y), \tag{1}$

and

$\det X^T = \det X, \tag{2}$

which hold for any two $n \times n$ matrices $X$, $Y$,and the fact that $\det D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, is the product of its diagonal entries.

From (1), we have, for invertible $X$,

$(\det X)(\det X^{-1}) = \det (XX^{-1}) = \det(I) = 1, \tag{3}$

whence

$\det X^{-1} = (\det X)^{-1}; \tag{4}$

Since

$\det ((2A)^{-1} B^T) = 1, \tag{5}$

we have

$\det (2^{-1}I) \det A^{-1} \det B^T = \det ((2A)^{-1} B^T) = 1, \tag{6}$,

and also,

$\det (2^{-1}I) = 2^{-n}, \tag{7}$

so using (2) and (4) we find

$2^{-n} (\det A)^{-1} \det B = 1, \tag{8}$

or

$\det B = 2^n \det A; \tag{9}$

also,

$\det (4I) \det B^{-1} \det A^3 = \det (4IB^{-1}A^3) = \det (4B^{-1}A^3) = 2^{-1}, \tag{10}$

and

$\det(4I) = 4^n = 2^{2n}, \tag{11}$

so with the aid of (1), (2) and (4) again

$2^{2n} (\det B)^{-1} (\det A)^3 = 2^{-1}, \tag{12}$

so

$\det B = 2^{2n + 1} (\det A)^3; \tag{13}$

combining (9) and (13):

$2^n \det A = 2^{2n + 1} (\det A)^3; \tag{14}$

thus since we have been (tacitly) assuming $\det A \ne 0$,

$(\det A)^2 = 2^{-(n + 1)}, \tag{15}$

or

$\det A = \sqrt{2^{-(n + 1)}}; \tag{16}$

by (9),

$\det B = 2^n\sqrt{2^{-(n + 1)}} = \sqrt{2^{(n - 1)}}. \tag{17}$

With $n = 3$ we have

$\det A = \sqrt{2^{-4}} = 2^{-2}, \tag{18}$

and

$\det B = \sqrt {2^2} = 2. \tag{19}$

These results are easily checked.